# How to make Konsole invoke konsole -ls for all users?

Tags: bash, shell, kde, slackware, konsole

I admin a linux domain for students. The students use their lab workstations in graphical mode, but often use Konsole on KDE for ssh and programming tasks.

I know Konsole can be configured through the GUI to use the -ls arguments to start a login shell. However, I would like to save the students and their professors the trouble of doing this every semester.

So, is there a command-line-accessible place (such as a config file) I can set the arguments for them on the workstations, for the GUI Konsole to automatically start in login shell mode?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I can find no place in the configuration of konsole where you can do this. The easiest way may be to place the following in the system wide /etc/profile:
alias konsole='konsole --ls'

Comment: Let me know if it works out for you.